# Is a group $G$ a subgroup of itself?

Tags: group-theory

I'd like to know if $G$ (generic group) is a subgroup of $G$. I'm not sure about that because I didn't prove that $ab^{-1} \in G$ for $a,b \in G$. The associativity, identity element and inverse element don't seem imply to $G<G$ but the such statement seems to make a little bit of sense.

The point which lead me to want to know that is that doing this I think I'm able to proof that $G$ is closed under its operator.

Note that for $a=b$ it's true as $aa^{-1}=e \in G$

Comment: Why are you not sure? Look again at the definition of a group, then for $a,b\in G$ it follows what you want.

Comment: $G$ is a subgroup of itself. To prove that the subgroup conditions hold, you should use the properties of the group $G$.

Comment: I don't see where the statements that tell us what a group is (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) implies to $G<G$, just for $b=a$. I really don't think it's obvious.

Comment: It is obvious. First, since $b\in G$ also $b^{-1}$ in $G$. Second, if two elements are in $G$, so is the product. Done.

Comment: Intuitively speaking, a subgroup is a subset of $G$ that is also a group. In set theory, $U$ can be a subset of itself (when we don't want that to happen we need to specify we're looking for a *proper subgroup*). Since $G$ is a subset of $G$ and is a group, it follows that it is a subgroup of $G$. It is not a "proper" subgroup.

Comment: Given a group, G, G and the empty set are the "trivial subgroups".

Comment: @GeorgeIvey Hmmm... "nontrivial" often just means not equal to $\{e\}$, and "proper" means not equal to $G$. $G$ is the "improper" subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

> **The One-step Subgroup Test**: A subset $S$ of a group $H$ is a subgroup of $H$ if and only if both
>
> 1. $S$ is nonempty.
> 2. for all $a,b\in S$, we have $ab^{-1}\in S$.

Consider a group $G$.

Since $G$ is a group, $e\in G$, so $G$ is nonempty.

Clearly $G\subseteq G$.

Let $g,h\in G$. Then, since $G$ is a group, $gh^{-1}\in G$.

Hence $G\le G$.

---

Alternatively, let $r,s,t\in G$.

Again, $G\subseteq G$.

Since $G$ is a group, the operation is associative, so indeed

$$r(st)=(rs)t.$$

Note that $G$ is closed by definition, so indeed $G$ is closed as a subset of $G$ under the operation.

We have $e\in G$ by definition of a group. Hence the identity is in $G$.

Since $r\in G$, we have $r^{-1}\in G$ by definition of a group.

Hence $G$ is a group that is a subset of $G$ under the operation of $G$. (This should, in fact, be immediate; formally, though, the statements above are necessary.)

Hence $G$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I didnt know that $gh^{-1} \in G$ holds for any group I though it would hold just for subgroups. Why would that be closed? I didn't know that a group is always closed.

Comment: @DaviAmérico That's part of the definition! Either because you say so explicitly, or because you use the word "operation", whose definition requires closure. If whatever source you are using is not saying this, chuck it away.

Answer (score 0):

We want to prove that

If $G$ is a group then it is a subgroup of itself.

Proof- Let $G$ be a group with the binary operation $\circ$ (A group is a pair $(G,\circ)$), where $G$ is a non empty set and $\circ$ is a binary operation on $G$ which is associative, having identity and unique inverse for each element of $G$).

We say that a non empty subset $H$ of $G$ is a $\textbf{subgroup}$ of $G$ if $(H,\circ)$ is itself a group. From this definition it can be easily seen that $G$ is a subgroup of itself.

Now there is a result $H$ is subgroup of $(G,\circ)$ $\iff$ $\forall\ a,b\in H,\ a\circ b^{-1}\in H$.

For this let $a,b\in G$. Then $b^{-1}\in G$. So we have $a,b^{-1}\in G$.  Now since $\circ$ is a binary operation on $G$ $\Rightarrow a\circ b^{-1}\in G.$ This proves the result.

If you still feel some problem, I suggest you to please read the definition of binary operation and its importance in the definition of group.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that if $(G,\star)$ is a group, then by definition, a subgroup of $(G,\star)$ is any couple $(H,\star)$ such that $H\subset G$ (in particular $G\subset G$) and $(H,\star)$ is a group.